# How to use actionbar in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-actionbar, android-edittext

I have an activity in which i want to use webview. And the url is to be entered by user. I want an edittext and a button on the actionbar for it.. How to do that, please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html) for tutorials on customizing the Action Bar. You can follow that tutorial to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

for WebView with full screen

```
public class Recipie extends Activity
```

For action bar and navigation drawer

```
public class Recipie extends AppCompatActivity
```